# How to update "physical path" of a site on IIS 10 using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, web-administration

When creating a site I manage to set the path with the following line of code

```
New-WebSite -Name "mysite" -port 8084 -PhysicalPath "c:\inetpub\wwwroot" -ApplicationPool "myappPool"
```

I have tried to figure out how to update the path, nothing found via Configuration Editor. I thought I had it with the following command

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='mysite']/virtualDirectoryDefaults" -name "physicalPath" -value "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite"
```

...but, it is not virtualdirectory I want to update, but the actual site...

Comment: The new cmdlets should be easier to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets

Comment: But still not able to see the physicalPath

PS C:\> $Site = Get-IISSite "Default Web Site"
PS C:\> $Site.Attributes

Where could it be?

Comment: That's because the physical path is a property under virtual directory, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Open applicationHost.config and you should soon learn it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use below PowerShell command to change the iis site physical path.

run PowerShell as administrator.

run below command:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module WebAdministration
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\sitea -name physicalPath -value "D:\s1"
```

after changing the path open iis manager and refresh the site.

Comment: Thanks, I spend almost an hour searching for it.