# How do i make IIS Website Site Name check

Tags: powershell

I updated my script and solved my previous issues about my second conditional did not triggered when i called my function. But now i found new problems: 1. when how do i put user input outside the function without changing my function template " function createIISWebsite($siteName,$sitePath,$siteUrl) "so, the function will be run when automatically without me manually calling it.

```
 function createIISWebsite($siteName,$sitePath,$siteUrl) {

    #Asking for User input
    $siteName = Read-Host "siteName: "
    $sitePath = Read-Host "sitePath: "
    $siteUrl = Read-Host "siteUrl: "
    
    try {
        
        # Check if site name already exists and update site path
        if ((Get-Website $siteName) -and (Test-Path $sitePath) )

            { Set-Location $sitePath  
              Write-Host "$siteName " -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline; 
              Write-Host "already exist, updated the site path to "-NoNewline; 
              Write-Host "$sitePath "-ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline;  
              Write-Host "and you can access it via "-NoNewline;
              Write-Host "$siteUrl"-ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline;}
              
        # if not exists create new website * can specify port and protocol "http or https"
        # using out-null for cleaner output
        else 
            { $sitePort = Read-Host "Input Port: "
              $siteProtocolType = Read-Host "Input Protocol Type http or https: "
              New-Website -Name $siteName  -HostHeader $siteUrl -PhysicalPath $sitePath | Out-Null
              New-WebBinding -Name $siteName -Port $sitePort -Protocol $siteProtocolType
              Write-Host $siteName "successfully created, you can access it via" $siteUrl -ForegroundColor Green }
        }
    catch
            {Write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"}
            
return

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if a sitename already exists, use [Get-IISSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iissite?view=windowsserver2022-ps).
Because you are asking for user input **inside** the function, there is no need for any of the function parameters.
`return` at the end of the function is also not needed.

Try:

```
function createIISWebsite {

    #Asking for User input
    $siteName = Read-Host "siteName: "
    $sitePath = Read-Host "sitePath: "
    $siteUrl  = Read-Host "siteUrl: "
    
    $existingSite = Get-IISSite -Name $siteName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # check If the site name already exists, update the existing using new input parameter
    if ($existingSite) {
        Write-Host "$siteName already exist, updated the site path to $sitePath and you can access it via $siteUrl"
    }
    #if not exist create new website using port 80 and shows successfully created new site
    else { 
        try {
            $null = New-Website -Name $siteName -Port 80 -HostHeader $siteUrl -PhysicalPath $sitePath -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "$siteName successfully created, you can access it via $siteUrl"
        }
        catch {
            Write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you do want to use parameters, then just do the `Read-Host` lines **outside** of the function like

```
function createIISWebsite {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$siteName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$sitePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [string]$siteUrl
    )
    $existingSite = Get-IISSite -Name $siteName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # check If the site name already exists, update the existing using new input parameter
    if ($existingSite) {
        try {
            # update the site physical path to whatever is in variable $sitePath
            # I don't know your configuration, but the path for Set-ItemProperty in IIS usually starts with "IIS:\Sites\"
            Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$siteName" -Name physicalPath -Value $sitePath -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "$siteName already exist, updated the site path to $sitePath and you can access it via $siteUrl"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Error updating the site's physical path:`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    # if not exist create new website using port 80 and shows successfully created new site
    else { 
        try {
            $null = New-Website -Name $siteName -Port 80 -HostHeader $siteUrl -PhysicalPath $sitePath -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "$siteName successfully created, you can access it via $siteUrl"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Error creating new website:`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}

#Asking for User input
$siteName = Read-Host "siteName: "
$sitePath = Read-Host "sitePath: "
$siteUrl  = Read-Host "siteUrl: "

# now call the function with parameters NAMED
createIISWebsite -siteName $siteName -sitePath $sitePath -siteUrl $siteUrl

# or without the parameter names, just by position:
# createIISWebsite $siteName $sitePath $siteUrl
```

Comment: actually , i found the solution which is similar to your solution but now as per you said about function parameters actually it need to be done using parameters but i don't know how to implement input outside the function without messing it up and also `return` is needed too not sure why. Do you have solution regarding this

Comment: @bobmar I have added an example how to use the function with parameters. As said, a single command `return` as the last line of a function is unneeded. When a function is done, it will return automatically to the calling script. Especially here, since the function does not actually return anything.

Comment: but can i do it without putting mandatory  since it changed the template and position? and also `return`  and also i changed my code in the question above way different than the one you put will it be effected ?

Comment: @bobmar If you leave out `Mandatory`, chances are you do not get a value sent through as parameter. You can change leave out the `Position`'s of course, but then you either need to always check if you are sending the parameters in the expected order or always use them as Named parameters.

Comment: alright it is working fine now  without mandatory and position but i cant  make `set-location` works. the current path of website still using old one when i tried to change it to new path. it was working few hours ago not sure what i did wrong

Comment: @bobmar I guess it all depends on what you give as value for parameter `sitePath`. The function does not set a new path for an existing siteName; it only writes information to the console. If you want to **update** the physical path for a site in IIS, you need to do what is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59081204/9898643). `Set-Location` only sets the **current working location** of PowerShell to a specified location`

Comment: but when i check on IIS Manager it was changed to specify location now it doesnt work anymore. and for the link u gave it doesnt work for me because my sitepath is not on IIS:\Sites\sitea i tried to change it to $sitePath still doesnt work

Comment: @bobmar You have combined the test if the site name exists with a test to see if the given site path exist. What you want is first test if the site **Name** exists and inside that set the physical path to whatever is set in parameter `$sitePath`. Again, `Set-Location` does not set the path for the site, you need `Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$siteName" -Name physicalPath -value $sitePath` to actually set the physical path for the site with that name.

Comment: @bobmar Please see my edited 2nd code. After changing the path open iis manager and refresh the site